# Embed Authenticated SharePoint Page in React Application

Tags: office-365, authentication, react, sso

I have an ask to figure out if it is possible to embed SharePoint pages into a website that is based on React. Our company uses SSO/Okta to login to our applications, including Office365. I've managed to simply iFrame a page in as a test and so long as the user has already logged into Office365 the iFrame displays. If the user has not already logged in, the iFrame will no display.

Is it possible to automatically login the user via SSO/Okta on the React side and display SharePoint pages (via iFrame or other embedding means) and auto-login, or provide a login to Office365/SharePoint within the React/Web application if the user has not yet logged in?